# wordpress plugin Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function update() on null

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a form to update data from index.php to update.php. I am getting Fatal Error on update.php with the below code

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update( 
    'wp_table', 
    array( 
        'apikey' => '$apikey',      // string
        'locid' => '$locid',
        'appid' => '$appid',
        'ulr' => '$ulr' 
    ), 
    array( 'id' => '1' ), 
    array( 
        '%s',       // value1
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s'    
    ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
```

I dont know where I am Doing wrong???

Comment: Probably, `$wpdb` is not defined? Where should it come from?

Comment: `global $wpdb;` is this not defining??? How to define then???

Comment: How does your script start? `global $wpdb;` does not instantiate the database object - probably, you have to require something before?

Comment: `require_once('../../../wp-load.php'); ` solved the problem . Thanks @NicoHaase